# WPF C# Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a code in c# to do image processing. I want to use threading and i suppose threading in WPF application is little different. I tried to run thread but it only works when the function is void(), i.e does not take any arguments.

However, my function is taking 3 arguemnts like this

```
frame_extract.Frame_Processing(_colorFrame_, widht, height);
```

So therefore the following does not work

```
depth_Threads = new System.Threading.Thread(**) since ** takes on void() type.
```

perhaps i am missing something, but my question is how can i work with threading for functions that take arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the TPL.

It should then be something like:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => frame_extract.Frame_Processing(_colorFrame_, widht, height));
```

But be aware that you might have to marshal to the ui-thread.

If you want to create the thread in the ui thread and want the new thread to interact with mentioned ui thread, something like the following should work:

```
var task = new Task(() => frame_extract.Frame_Processing(_colorFrame_, widht, height));
task.Start(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

That should work.

Comment: it works fine, but i see you said marshal to ui-thread. Can you explain what that meant. Sorry since I am new to this i am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if that's what you want, but I think you need to do this :

```
depth_Threads = new System.Threading.Thread(()=>frame_extract.Frame_Processing(_colorFrame_, widht, height));
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what values you are passing in. Sometimes if you are using objects, they are locked to a given thread in which case you need to create duplicates prior and then pass the duplicates into the new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following. Your method should receive single object argument like this `void SomeVoid(object obj)`. Make an object array with all variables that you want to pass to the method `SomeVoid` like this `object[] objArr = { arg1, arg2, arg3 };` and then call the Start method of thread object with `objArr` argument since the Start() method receives one object parameter. Now back to your method, cast and obj received from Start method to an object array like this `object arr = obj as object[];` and then you can access those 3 arguments like this `arr[0] arr[1]` and `arr[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ParameterizedThreadStart` class.

1) Create a class who will holds your three arguments

```
 public class FrameProcessingArguments
 {
     public object ColorFrame { get; set; }
     public int Width { get; set; }
     public int Height { get; set; }
 }
```

2) Modify your `Frame_Processing` method to take as parameter an instance of `Object` and inside it, cast that instance as a `FrameProcessingArguments`

```
if (arguments == null) throw new NullArgumentException();
if(arguments.GetType() != typeof(FrameProcessingArguments)) throw new InvalidTypeException();
FrameProcessingArguments _arguments = (FrameProcessingArguments) arguments;
```

3) Create and start your thread

```
FrameProcessingArguments arguments = new FrameProcessingArguments() 
{
     ColorFrame = null,
     Width = 800,
     Height = 600
}

Thread thread = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(frame_extract.Frame_Processing));
// You can also let the compiler infers the appropriate delegate creation syntax:
// and use the short form : Thread thread = new Thread(frame_extract.Frame_Processing);
thread.Start (arguments);
```